# Datos especificos usando el with - Laravel 5.3 Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

estoy aprendiendo laravel eloquent y tambien el uso del with. Se que te devuelve un array en cascada (o asi lo llamo yo), pero lo que no me gusta es que te devuelva todos los datos. Por ejemplo tengo estas tablas con sus campos

```
Users: id_user, username, info_id, email
Posts: id_post, user_id,title, description, category
Comments: id_comment, post_id, comment, image
```

Ya deben saber las relaciones por la forma en como estan los campos (Estoy poniendo un ejemplo, no es un trabajo real). De esto al hacer uso del `with` seria:
`User::with('post.comments')` y el resultado saldria:

```
[
  {
    id_user,
    username,
    info_id
    email,
    post: [
      {
        id_post,
        user_id,
        title,
        description,
        category,
        comments: [
          {
            id_comment,
            post_id,
            comment,
            image
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Nuevamente recalco que esto es un ejemplo y deben suponer que los modelos, relaciones, etc ya estan hechas correctamente, ahora, lo quiero saber ahora como dice el titulo:**Como saco datos especificos usando el with**

Por ejemplo, quiero solamente el campo `image` y el campo `description`

```
[
  {
    image,
    description
  }
]
```

Hasta ahora he usado eso, el `with`, pero se me esta complicando hacer varias cosas porque no obtengo campos especificos, antes usaba `Query Builder` y con solo hacer `joins` obtenia todos los resultados y podria filtrar con un `select` para obtener lo que quiero, pero nose como hacerlo usando `Eloquent` o tal vez no se usa el with sino otra cosa, gracias

Comment: @BetaM muestrenme esas soluciones quiero aprender y entre mas mejor, lo que intente? Vi que en los modelos se le puede poner un apartado para mostrar y ocultar datos y asi obtener campos especificos, pero eso no es lo que quiero

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿porque estas aprendiendo Laravel con una versión tan vieja?
Deberías empezar al menos por la 6 que es la última LTS publicada.

Answer (score 3):

Como bien comentas una opción es que en el modelo establezcas una propiedad privada llamada [`$hidden`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json) igualándola con un array de atributos, el detalle es que cada columna aquí se ocultará en todas las consultas de Eloquent que involucren al modelo donde esta quedó declarada.

Sin embargo considera que:

La propia documentación de Laravel nos indica una forma *simple* en su apartado [*eager loading specific columns*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns)<sup>1</sup> como cargar columnas específicas de la relación declarada.

Para este ejemplo yo estoy:

- Agregando el método `select` a nivel del modelo principal donde específico que columnas deseo

  - De entre las columnas que puedes seleccionar, la llave primaria debe estar presente
- Dentro del método `with` y empezando la declaración por el símbolo de `:` indicas todas las columnas que deseas recuperar

  - Sin embargo es importante notar que la llave foránea debe estar presente

    ```
    Modelo::select(['id', 'columnaX', 'columnaY'])
           ->with('relacion:id,llave_foranea,columnaA,columnaB')
           ->get();
    ```

Para el caso de relaciones anidadas, podemos pasarlas dentro de un array asociativo dentro del método `with` y usando una función en cada una que nos ayude a construir un `select` personalizado en cada caso

```
Modelo::select([
                'llavePrimaria', 
                'columnaU'
            ])->with([
                        'relacion1' => function($query) {
                            $query->select(['llavePrimaria', 'columnaX', 'llave_foranea']);
                        },
                        'relacion1.relacionAnidada' => function ($query) {
                            $query->select(['columnaY', 'llave_foranea']);
                        }
            ])->get();
```

Básicamente es:

- Del modelo principal selecciona las columnas deseadas incluyendo la llave primaria
- De la primer relación directa que tiene el modelo elige la llave primaria y también la llave foránea entre las demás que necesitas
- La relación anidada debe incluir entre las demás columnas que necesites también la llave foránea que la vincula con la primer relación

**Nota importante**<sup>1</sup>

La documentación nos hace una específicación importante al respecto sobre esta manera de seleccionar y cito:

> When using this feature, you should always include the id column and any relevant foreign key columns in the list of columns you wish to retrieve.

Que se puede traducir como:

> Cuando se usa esta característica, siempre debes incluir la columna de id y cualquier columna de llave foránea relevante en la lista de columnas que deseas recuperar.

Tienes otras opciones como [trabajar con local query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes) y construir por cada modelo deseado `selects` personalizados para las columnas deseadas y posterior solo invocarlos en tu consulta, pero la idea expuesta anteriormente en el ejemplo dado es básicamente la misma incluye la llave primaria y la llave foránea para que *Eloquent comprenda la relación declarada*.

**Importante**

- [El eager loading de columnas específicas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) existe o esta en la documentación desde la versión 5.5
- Sin embargo la segunda parte que propongo en mi respuesta si te debería estar funcionando

Comment: Esto tambien funciona en laravel 5.3? Y como seria si tendria que usar muchos with, por ejemplo `with('relacion:id,llave_foranea,columnaA,columnaB.relacion2.relacion3.relacion4'`

Comment: @Mario tal como edité en mi respuesta, la primer parte que expongo existe documentada desde la versión 5.5, en caso de que no te funcione, prueba con la segunda opción donde para elegir columnas específicas lo hacemos a través de una función asignada como valor a la relación dentro de un array asociativo

Comment: Una consulta, de esta pregunta, entonces no existe tal forma para que salga como dice `image,description`. Porque usando el `select` o `relacion:id,llave_foranea...`. Igual va salir anidado con el nombre `relacion` y para recorrerlo seria digamos `modelo['relacion1']['relacion2']['image']`. Pero en mi caso yo quiero `modelo['image']`

Comment: @JuanRivera hasta donde se no

Comment: Entonces tendrias alguna alternativa a eso? Porque si una BD tiene mas de 10 tablas, tendria que recorrer mucho (`modelo['relacion1']['relacion2']....`)  para sacar 1 dato si esque quiero eso, pero aun asi existira casos. O simplemente uso `Query Builder`, relaciono, filtro y obtengo lo que quiero. Si la respuesta es extensa hare una pregunta para aclarar ahi las cosas

Comment: @JuanRivera te invito a publicar la duda, en la comunidad existe gente conocedora de Laravel que te puede aportar mucho

Comment: @BetaM listo, espero que se me haya entendido al preguntar, sino me ayudarias editando mi pregunta

Comment: @JuanRivera si de hecho estoy construyendo una posible respuesta