# Eloquent (Modelos) - Query Builder (Joins) Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, querybuilder

Para que se entienda la pregunta que quiero hacer, pondre ejemplos:

1. En Eloquent utilizamos modelos para hacer las relaciones y asi poder obtener datos. De esto laravel nos ofrece diversos metodos para obtener la data como el `with` que al utilizarlo nos devuelve un resultado estructurado:

- Relacion 01

```
[
  {
    modelo,
    relacion1 : {
      relacion2: {
      .
      .
      .
      }
    }
  }
]
```

2. En Query Builder, las relaciones la hacemos directamente en el controlador y no creamos un "Modelo" para poder hacerlas asi que hacemos uso de los `JOINS` para ello y obtener los datos. La ventaja de esto es que podemos hacer consultas directamente como cuando escribimos en la BD usando `join,where,select,etc` y nos devolvera un resultado no estructurado (A esto me refiero como solamente data:)

- Relacion 02

```
[
  {
    dato1,
    dato2,
    dato3
  },
  {
    dato4,
    dato5,
    dato6
  }
]
```

Ahora bien mi pregunta seria la siguiente: ¿En Eloquent, haciendo uso del `with` u otro metodo, podemos obtener esta estructura o filtrar para obtener datos especificos? (No me refiero usar `JOINS` en eloquent)

A lo que me refiero es que para poder leer la `Relacion 01`, tenemos que hacer:

`modelo[relacion1][relacion2][relacion3]....[dato que quiero]` Para obtener el campo que queramos

Pero en `Query Builder` no pasa eso porque como te devuelve `no-estructurado`, solo se tiene que hacer:

`result['dato que quiero']`

Espero que se haya entendido mi consulta, gracias a todos

Comment: Tengo entendido que no puedes hacer eso, ya que la principal característica de usar Eloquent es que todo se comporta como objeto, así que si quieres obtener el dato que viene de alguna relación vas a tener que depender de sus relaciones padres.

Comment: Entiendo, pero habra una funcion PHP para que obtenga lo que quiero? Esto seria otra pregunta pero es parte de la que hize como una solucion @FernandoTorres

Comment: Podrías ocupar lo inverso de la relación, lee sobre eso aquí, que en lugar de ir a la tabla posts primero y traer los comentarios, en lugar de eso vas a la tabla de comentarios directamente enlazando el id del post, mira el ejemplo acá https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

Comment: Lo que quiero evitar en si es `modelo[relacion1][relacion2]...[dato que quiero]`

Comment: Si pero segun lo que vi no es posible de igual forma gracias

Answer (score 2):

Ambas salidas son información *estructurada*, pero debemos distinguir algunos aspectos relevantes:

**Por medio del builder de Eloquent**

- Cuando haces uso de las relaciones de Eloquent y por ende de los métodos del builder de Eloquent obtendrás como salida:

  - Las objetos relacionados de forma anidada y agrupados dentro de una colección mas o menos así:

    ```
      [
          {
              ...........,
              ...........
              "relacion": [
                  {
                      .......,
                      .......
                  },
                  {
                      .......,
                      .......
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
    ```
  - El objeto relacionado anidado dentro del objeto principal mas o menos así:

    ```
      [
          {
              ...........,
              ...........
              "relacion": {
                  ...........,
                  ...........
              }
          }
      ]
    ```

Cada una de los 2 salidas anteriormente mencionadas dependerá de que estés consultando y por ende solicitando como respuesta.

**Por medio del query builder**

- Ahora por otro lado cuando usas los métodos del query builder como el *join* puedes obtener una salida como esta:

  ```
   [
    {
        .........,
        .........
    },
    {
        ..........,
        ..........
    }
   ]
  ```

Entonces técnicamente:

- Ambas salidas nos dan información *estructurada* (aunque de distinta forma)

  - Si analizas, el builder de Eloquent ofrece una salida mas expresiva al agrupar los modelos o modelo relacionados con el modelo al que esta vinculado
- La salida que da el query builder aunque válida y funcional nos otorga objetos repetidos por cada vez que A esté relacionada con B.
- En realidad nada te limita a que si trabajas con las relaciones de Eloquent puedas *extraer* la data de cada colección u objeto y colocarla en un array nuevo aunque... no lo considero adecuado:

  - Estás agregando una tarea extra que procesar
  - Si buscas una salida de array de objetos igual y te conviene mas que tu consulta use un simple join(s)

Ahora a nivel de las consultas, considera que:

- Al trabajar con la capa de modelos tienes funcionalidades extra que te permiten extraer la data solicitada de manera mas eficiente; es decir perfectamente puedes indicar en la relación definida que atributos traer de esa entidad:

  ```
  public function relacion()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo(Modelo::class)->select(['pk', 'atributo1']);
  }
  ```

Con lo anterior *evitas* tener que construir el **`select`** directo en la consulta.

- O bien puedes mover los **`selects`** a nivel de tus modelos por medio de [local query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes) para tener una consulta lo mas simple posible mas o menos así:

Local query scope

```
public function scopeCustomSelect($query)
{
    return $query->select(['pk', 'atributo1', ...., 'atributoN']);
}
```

Consulta usando el local query scope:

```
 return Modelo::with(['relacion' => fn($query) => $query->customSelect() ])->get();
```

- O bien puedes dejar los **`select`** dentro de la misma consulta [como expongo en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/405928/datos-especificos-usando-el-with-laravel-5-3-eloquent/405954#405954)

**Comentarios finales**

1. Laravel como framework es versártil y técnicamente no te obliga a usar todas y cada una de sus herramientas, pero es importante notar las ventajas que cada una puede tener, la sintaxis para consultar mediante las relaciones de Eloquent no es compleja, es expresiva y fácil de mantener (*la mayoría de las veces es mas fácil pensar en una consulta por medio de POO que por medio de SQL*), sin embargo si no es lo que *acomode a nuestras necesidades* podemos prescindir de ella.
2. No tiene mucho caso tratar de que los métodos de consulta entreguen la data formateada de una manera diferente a como están programados para hacerlo (*aunque insisto puedes componer un script que itere las colecciones y llevar esos datos a una estructura de datos nueva*)
3. Esta *respuesta* es una mera aproximación y **no debe tomarse como la solución definitiva a la duda expuesta**, siempre es bueno esperar a conocer lo que otros pueden aportar