# Eloquent o Query builder?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Voy a montar un proyecto para la empresa que trabajo y es una inmobiliaria, la cosa es que necesitamos un gestor de pisos, donde se podra modificar los que hay , visibles o no, precios, etc , un poco un crud,

Y tambien por detras habra un "backoffice" tipo crm que alli se podran gestionar cosas mas internas de los trabajadores y estadisticas, y printar pfd's. y varias cosas más.

La cosa es que he empezado con laravel hace unos meses y tengo un nivel intermedio, pero tengo una gran duda.

Si yo realmente lo que busco es un **proyecto Escalable, a largo plazo, y que se monte de la forma más rápida y óptima**, que me iría mejor, Eloquent ( con modelos y todo) o Query builder¿?

**Cúales son las diferencias mas grandes entre uno y otro? Se nota mucho la ayuda en Eloquent?**

He visto que Eloquent es un rollo por que hay que configurar mucho de los modelos y eso, ademas que estan hecho para cogerlo en ingles y hay que cambiar bastantes cosas para las relaciones y eso, Pero tambien se puede hacer con query builder, y no sería tanta perdida de tiempo no? Sinceramente Eloquent lo veo un poco perdida de tiempo y es mas para programadores avanzados, y desde mi nivel ( sql medio y laravel medio) creo que me iría mejor por mis conocimientos y por el proyecto ( que necesitaria empezar a realizar cambios rapido) Hace un año monte un proyecto con Eloquent y me quede muy atascado con las relaciones.....

Alguien me da su punto de vista? Que tenga más experiencia y me pueda guiar? Solamente busco la forma más optima y que luego no tenga que cambiar de eloquent a query builder o viceversa.

Gracias!

Comment: La pregunta esta basada en opiones, por eso quedara cerrada. Por otro lado te recomiendo ver lo siguiente para que veas un poco mas la diferencia entre trabajar con modelos(Eloquent) y joins(Query Builder) https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/406760

Comment: Estás un poco confundido, todos los modelos son constructores de consultas como puedes leer [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#building-queries), entonces aún con los modelos puedes emplear todos los los métodos que **provee el query builder**, así que **no** deberías verlos como algo aislado el uno del otro

Comment: MI pregunta es simple, que es mejor Eloquent o Query builder, y sus diferencias a puntos de vista de usuarios experimentados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La pauta modelo-vista-controlador la deberías respetar, ya sea que trabajes con eloquent o query builder, no sé qué es lo que ves como complejo pero definiendo los modelos y sus relaciones luego es todo mucho más simple, las relaciones entre tablas quedan definidas en el modelo y luego sólo las utilizas.

El objeto que te devuelve tiene algunas diferencias, en mi proyecto utilizo a veces eloquent y a veces query builder.

Agrego un ejemplo de la documentación con lo que me resulta más útil de Eloquent, la definición y manejo de relaciones entre tablas, tomamos el ejemplo clásico de post y comentarios sobre esos post, tenemos una tabla de cada uno y los comments tendrán un post_id, entonces en el modelo de los Post tendremos:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
/**
 * Get the comments for the blog post.
 */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}
```

Ahí la relación de un post a muchos comentarios ya está armada, luego en un controlador accedemos directamente a los comments de un post, por ejemplo:

```
use App\Models\Post;

$comments = Post::find(1)->comments;

foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    //
}
```

Y en una vista para mostrar los comentarios se trabaja de forma similar. La relación y cualquier SQL es invisible tanto en controladores como vistas, está definida en el modelo, esto query builder no lo permite. Después están el resto de las relaciones (muchos a uno, muchos a muchos, etc) puse sólo la más simple.

Además podés generar funciones que te sean útiles en el modelo, para tenerlas disponibles en controlador o vistas, por ejemplo tengo una para calcular el monto total en un carrito de compras con varios productos.

La documentación en [Laravel Doc](https://www.laravel.com) es muy buena, en el apartado de modelos se explica claramente como definir los modelos, y como funcionan las relaciones luego.

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Entiendo, y lo que me gustaría saber es por que aveces tu usas query builder y otras  Eloquent? Que me iría mejora para mi proyecto? Ahora mismo creo que aprendería bastante bien y rapido Eloquent, pero es que con query builder lo veo bastante bien, y rapido

Comment: Actualice el comentario.

Comment: En realidad aún trabajando con los modelos podemos usar todos los métodos del query builder, lo que está respuesta expone son las ventajas y diferencias entre joins regulares y el uso de las relaciones que usan subconsultas

Comment: Entonces entiendo que si puedo usar Eloquent hare las sentencias de una forma mucho más facil y rapida, además que es mas simple el tema de las relaciones. Eso necesito, por saber un poco los cambios entre una y otra, aver si Eloquent me presupone mucho tiempo de configuracion pues lo iba a descartar, pero veo que no es el caso