# Como obtener un solo campo de una tabla relacionada en laravel?

Tags: laravel, api

como podria obtener un solo dato de una tabla relacionada en laravel, cuando uso with me bota este resultado:

```
{
 "id":1,
 "detalle":"mesa 1",
 "sucursal":{
      "id":1,
      "nombre":"sucursal 1",
      "estado":1
      }
}
```

pero lo que necesito es que solo me muestre el nombre de la sucursal:

```
{
 "id":1,
 "detalle":"mesa 1",
 "sucursal":"sucursal 1"
}
```

Comment: Hace tiempo habia preguntado algo "similar": https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/406760 Pero si no te sirve, muestranos la consulta que haces

Comment: hay varias cosas que deberías poner en tu pregunta el modelo está relacionado ??, que tienes en el controlador ??, si realizaste bien la relación debería ser suficiente esto {{$nombre->sucursal->nombre}} aquí utilizas la consulta accede al modelo y dentro del modelo debe estar la relación acedes a ella y consulta el nombre   actualiza tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que utilizar un eager loading, indicando unicamente que columnas requieres:
Asumiendo que quieres todo tu objeto y los campos de tu relacion seria algo como lo siguiente:

```
$articulo = Articulo::with('sucursal:id,nombre')->get();

{
  "id":1,
  "detalle":"mesa 1",
  "sucursal":{
      "id":1,
      "nombre":"sucursal 1"
    }
}
```

O como lo menciona @walter podrías obtener únicamente el nombre después de haber buscado tu articulo, por ejemplo:

```
$nombreSucursal = $articulo->sucursal->nombre;
```

A continuación te dejo una referencia de la documentación de Laravel para que te quede mas claro: [Eager loading specific columns](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns)